# Sending Emails from Class Based views not working

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am trying to send an email when a post in a Class Based View is created but I am not receiving anything although I am receiving a success message after post created.

I am sure that email configuration is correct as I am receiving an email for a reset password

Here is the view

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'post']
    template_name = "post_form.html"
    success_url = "/score"
    success_message = "Thank you for Submitting a post"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.designer = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


def PostCreatedEmail(request):
    subject = 'Message subject'
    message = 'Message'
    send_mail(
        subject,
        message,
        'email@email.com',
        ['email@email.com'],
        fail_silently=False,
    )
    return render(request, '/score')
```

here is the urls:

```
    path('new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
```

Comment: The `send_mail` code is in `PostCreatedEmail`, but that's separate from the class based view. It looks like you want to move the `send_mail` code into `form_valid`. You can use `form.cleaned_data` to get data from the form.

Answer (score 0):

As *Alasdair* mentioned that your success message has nothing to do with you send_mail function due to wrong indentation. There are two potential fixes:

- Move your send_mail code to class-based-view and see if the email is still not being sent (it should), if still not then try to debug the code otherwise try second fix.
- I once fixed this issue by giving connection dictionary

```
     subject = 'Thank you for registering to our site'
          message = 'this is a test message'
          email_from = 'xyz@gmail.com'
          recipient_list = ['reciever@gmail.com', ]
          connection = [
              'xyz@gmail.com',
              'mypassword',
              False,
          ]
         send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list, connection)
```